# How can I fix my mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, light, import, geometry

I was importing a few models and I noticed that the lighting on the model's hands is messed up
[image]
(I'm 99% percent sure it's because of awful mesh).
[image]
I already tried degenerate dissolve, remesh, and merge by distance but nothing worked.
I'm still new at this so I have no idea what else to do.
How can I fix it? Is it even possible at this point?
(so I found out the lighting is messed up because of overlapping edges, but I still have no idea how to fix it)

Comment: Check normals, before panicking.. some faces are flipped?

Comment: mesh➤normal➤flip     right? Anyway, it looks same. I think It's an issue with overlapping faces or something.

Comment: maybe try Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: something slightly changed, https://imgur.com/a/M0oPziN

Comment: It looks as though your topology is very bad. You have some triangles with very small internal angles, that would be interpreted as pretty sharp kinks in the surface. Remeshing should help - you said you already tried, could you show the result of this operation as well?

Comment: please share your file (at least this part): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/n3K26Dok/

Comment: also here is a picture with remesh and smooth shading applied: https://imgur.com/a/6ajpKZ3 (it looks better, but remesh will mess up smooth surface)